# Why does this function not return anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function written in python 3

```
def nullstelle(f,a,b,counter=0,TOL=10 ** -4):
counter = counter + 1
if counter <= 100:
    g = f((a + b)/2)
    if f(a) * g <= 0:
        b = (a + b)/2
    else:
        a = (a + b)/2
    if abs(a-b) <= 2*TOL:
        return (a,b)
    else:
        nullstelle(f,a,b,counter,TOL)
else:
    return (a,b)
```

my problem is, that for the input

```
def f(x):
return x ** 3 -2
nullstelle(f,0,3)
```

it does not return anything. I really do not understand how this is possibly.

*Im sorry if this looks like a trivial question to you guys, but programming is absolutely not my main field of interest and I know nearly nothing about it (yet).*

Comment: What's the nested `else`; supposed to be doing?  Run `nullstelle` without returning anything?

Comment: Presumably `nullstelle(f,a,b,counter,TOL)` should be `return nullstelle(f,a,b,counter,TOL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this is a duplicate, but couldn't find one quickly.  The problem is that you're not returning the result of your recursive call, so you get `None` if you have to recurse.  Change that line to:

```
return nullstelle(f,a,b,counter,TOL)
```